# Need total value of two columns on Tooltip High charts

Tags: highcharts, tooltip

I need the Total count of column value on tooltip like
[image]

Comment: Are you trying to add information to the tooltip that is the total of CC Evaluation and SSC Evaluation at the given point?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a formatter function for the tooltip and build your own tooltip in the way you want. Example:

```
    tooltip: {
        formatter: function() {
            const series = this.series;
            const isColumnSeries = s => s.options.type === 'column';
            let result = `<span style="color: ${series.color}">${series.name}:</span> ${this.y}`;

            if (isColumnSeries(series)) {
                series.chart.series.forEach(s => {
                    if (s !== series && isColumnSeries(s)) {
                        result += `
                            <br /><span style="color: ${s.color}">${s.name}:</span>
                            ${s.points[this.point.index].y}
                        `;
                    }
                });
            }

            return result;
        }
    }
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/wv89buja/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.formatter